# Issue with rendering express template with node.js

Tags: node.js, http, express

I am facing an issue rendering the 'EJS' Express template while running the node.js server. I have provided the codes below. As you can see, I am implementing the `http.createServer(function (req, res)` to read and write messages to the client. But the template holding the HTML code doesn't get rendered. The main objective of the code is for the client to post a message 'Hello from Client' to the server and the server responding to the client with 'Hello from Server'.

app.js (Server Side)

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , request = require ('request')
  , cheerio = require ('cheerio')
  , $;
 

var app = express();
//console.log($('[class = "orange"]').attr('id'));
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var body="";
    console.log('Request received: ');
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body +=chunk;        
    });
    req.on('end', function(){
     console.log("Body: "+body);
     res.write('Hello from Server');
     res.end();
    });

}).listen(3000);
```

index.ejs (Client Side)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
      <input type="button" id="stopButton" value="Button1"/>
      <input type="button" id="stopButton2" value="Button2"/>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  <ul id="fruits">
  <li id= "1" class="apple">Apple</li>
  <li id = "2" class="orange">Orange</li>
  <li id = "3" class="pear">Pear</li>
</ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var formData = {data: "Hello from Client"};
           $.ajax({
               url: 'http://localhost:3000',
               dataType: "json",
               type: 'POST',
               data: formData,
               jsonpCallback: 'callback', 
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(ret.msg);
               },
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log("Error received");
               }
          });
      });
 </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

package.JSON

```css
{
  "name": "NewProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.2.6",
    "ejs": "*"
  }
}
```

Earlier I had tried using `app.get` which had worked.

What is the primary difference between using `app.get()`, `request()` and `http.createServer()`. When should we use what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gonna work that way. Have a loo at the docs:

- http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html

For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/hello', function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello from server");
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Also, please use a recent version of Express, yours is outdated.